# Access_Token on the Website by Implicit Method is a Security Implication?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a Server, on which i am testing `connect with Facebook` thing using API v2.2, When a user clicks on that button and Allows my Application he gets Authenticated and redirects back to my website `http://example.com/?#access_token=<REDACTED>` Great, so the REDACTED part is the `access_token` of the User who authorized.

Now, i am thinking on another Perspective that is it possible by Any Attacker to grab `access_token` on his site / Behalf of Other users? Note that, i have whitelist my domain `http://example.com` in Facebook developer so `redirect_uri` to another site won't work and I have a 1-2 page on my Website so clearly no URL - Redirection there... So any way to that something serious can happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible for an attacker to grab the access_token and request access on behalf of the user (resource owner). 
The assumption is basic security measures are in place before token exchange happens.

Such as:

- The communication is encrypted (https) - to avoid eavesdropping
- Use other token protection measures such as state parameter (and nonce if available) while sending implicit flow requests(more details about state parameter [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#checklogin) under optional parameters)  - mainly to prevent CSRF and
- The obvious one - do not share client secret in the client code (i.e public client )

Comment: I have Point 1 & Point 3 As protection but when the user requests the access_token, i haven't included Anti-CSRF Parameter `state` so How can Attacker's misuse the state parameter in this case? Even if i add extra `state` or not , i receive access_token in the same manner without difference @karthik

Comment: Let us say the access_token request URL is static (with static redirect uri and no state parameter) .. Anyone who observes your App's redirect uri could construct this staic token request and place a CSRF bait (as described under hacking step-by-step - http://homakov.blogspot.co.nz/2012/07/saferweb-most-common-oauth2.html) State parameter prevents this predictable static link. So  "State" parameter should be random and hard to guess.. it should be different for each access_token request and cannot be hard-coded. This prevents access_token requests made outside your app. SSL prevents token leak